# Wireless DHCP configuration fails on open network

Tags: wireless, 14.04, dhcp

I upgraded to Kubuntu Trusty last summer, and now that I'm back in school, I've noticed that my laptop has been failing to connect to the school's wireless (which is a completely open network). Every time I try to connect, it says *Connecting* for a while, and then it fails with the error message:

> IP configuration was unavailable

Or, if I play with the wireless setup (changing the driver, using direct commandline methods to connect to the network), then the error message changes:

> Authorization supplicant timed out

which is weird, because there's no need to authenticate anything (it's an open network).

It's interesting, because I know that my current setup can connect to a wireless network, as it works perfectly fine at home (which, unlike the school network, is locked down), and it uses DHCP there as well.

I've tried running `sudo dhclient wlan0`, but nothing happens.

My wireless card is a Broadcom BCM4313, and I'm using the `wl` driver.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8150392/ I should note that, despite the last line from `dmesg`, turning  power management off does not change anything. Also, I noticed that the `brcmsmac` driver was installed (which was what I was using before), but switching to it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your device in 14.04 brcmsmac is the best driver in most cases and it is best if power management is off.

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then reboot and make sure only the brcmsmac and bcma driver is loaded they are both currently blacklisted so you may have to unblacklist them by doing:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then remove `brcmsmac` and `bcma` save the file then close gedit and reboot.

You may have to install gksudo.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

(this will create or edit a configuration file that will override the default power management behavior) and enter the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

above exit0, then save gedit, close and reboot.

Change the channel to 6 if you can 4 people on that network are using 1 and 11 so that can cause issues.

After you make these changes if you still can not connect then post a new file from the script.

Comment: It worked without turning power management off (I don't know why it didn't work before). If there's a problem, I'll turn off power  management, but for now, I'll leave it on. Also, purging `bcmwl-kernel-source` removed the blacklist file in question.

Comment: I thought the purge command would but for some reason sometimes it does not.